# Passing Hook down to grandchild/multiple components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I'm wondering If I can pass a hook down multiple components. For example in my parent component I declare a hook and I pass the hook components into the child. And within that child I pass that hook into the grandchild and within the grandchild I set the state for the hook. I know that I can pass hooks from parent to child but unsure if I can do it for multiple components.

```
export const Parent = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState("")

  return(
      <Child data={data}, setData={setData}
   )

export const Child = ({data,setData}) => 
  return(
      <GrandChild data={data}, setData={setData}
  )

export const GrandChild = ({data,setData}) => 
  setData("hi")
  return(
      <div>{data}</div>
  )
```

Comment: Yes this is allowed.

Comment: but why? If you are doing this then you should revisit your architecture IMHO

Answer (score 1):

You can do this as many times as you want but there are better ways to do this like Redux or Context API. These tools are for preventing these kind of redundant actions.

Answer (score 0):

This can get messy very quickly as apps grow and can cause issues finding bugs and errors.  It is known as prop drilling.  I would strongly recommend the following documentation on
[useContext](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html)